# Is CRON secure?

Tags: security, cron

I want to install cron on my live web server to run a daily backup script of a local folder. Are there any security considerations I need to be aware of when installing cron?

My web server uses Ubuntu Linux 10.10.

Comment: What are you afraid of?

Comment: Which OS?  Please be specific.  Windows Cron is as insecure as Windows.  Linux cron is still Linux and has all the security of the OS installation.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a bit paranoid because it is the live system. It did not came pre-installed, so I was unsure if there are some security considerations that needed to be made.

Comment: @S.Lott Windows isn't insecure. Bad Windows admins make Windows insecure. If you let me admin a linux box it'll get broken into in about 2 minutes.

Comment: @mrdenny♦: "Windows Cron is as insecure as Windows" can be read as "Windows Cron is as secure as Windows".  It sure seemed like a trivial isomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence it's secure, but also it is another way for an attacker to, **once** compromised the system, make some backdoor persistent and/or auto-open it anytime you close it.

You can use the files `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny` to just make your user able to use it. Both have the same format: 1 username per line.

1. If `/etc/cron.allow` exists, **only** the users listed there would be able to have a crontab. No more files are taken into account. Kind of a whitelist.
2. If `/etc/cron.allow` does not exist, but `/etc/cron.deny` does, then **anyone but those listed there** can have a crontab. Kind of a blacklist.
3. If neither of them exist, then depending on the UNIX/Linux version then anyone may be allowed to use it, or just the super user (Debian/Ubuntu allow anybody, while redhat based versions seems to only allow root).

In ubuntu by default `/etc/cron.deny` exists. You can create `/etc/cron.allow` and put there just your user.

Take into account that these files only manage the users allowed to have a personal crontab (ie. execute `crontab -e`). The system-wide crontab (`/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d/*`,  `/etc/cron.daily/*`.  `/etc/cron.weekly/*`,  `/etc/cron.monthly/*`) will work regardless of the `cron.allow`/`cron.deny` files.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your third statement "3. If neither of them exist, then anyone can use it.". The crontab(1) man pages from different systems I have seem to all agree that "If neither of these files exists then only the super user will be allowed to use crontab.".

Comment: @GZBK it may depend on the system. On debian & ubuntu if these files do not exist then all users can use cron. Going to edit...

Comment: On my side I was referring to OpenBSD and OpenSUSE. Interesting enough I see now that FreeBSD document the behavior is "depending on site-dependant on configuration parameters" without expliciting the actual involved parameters. At last, the POSIX man page states that under such circumstances "only a process with appropriate privileges shall be allowed to submit a job", the concept of "appropriate privileges" remaining undefined as far as I know. Therefore in such circumstances I think the behavior is just variable and I would definitively recommend to avoid having none of these files present.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's secure. Just make sure the scripts you run with it are secure. Review them yourself and give them only the rights they need.